# Jacobi Quintuple Product Identity

Tags: combinatorics, quadratic-residues, theta-functions, q-analogs

I have to show the Jacobi Quintuple Product Identity
$$\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1-q^n)(1- \zeta q^{n-1})(1-\zeta^{-1} q^{n})(1-\zeta^{2} q^{2n-1})(1-\zeta^{-2}q^{2n-1}) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{\frac{3}{2}n^2-\frac{1}{2}n} \zeta^{3n} (1-\zeta q^n)$$

$q = e^{2 \pi i \tau}$
$ \zeta = e^{2 \pi iz}$

For this i have:
$$f(z, \tau)=
\nu_{0,1/2} (z, \tau ) \nu_{1/2,1/2} (2z, 2 \tau )$$

i muss show, that
$$f(z+1, \tau) =f(z ,\tau) , \,\,\,  f(z+\tau, \tau) =e^{-3 \pi i \tau   -6 \pi iz} f(z,\tau)$$

$$ => f( z, \tau) = \sum_{k=0}^{2}c_k(\tau) \nu_{k/3,0} (3z, 3\tau)$$
whit
$c_k (\tau)= e^{-\pi\tau k^2/3} \int_{0 }^{1} f(z, \tau) e^{-2 \pi ikz} dz
$

Than i muss show, that $c_0=0$ and $c_2 = -c_1$

=>than i  muss show, that $c_1(\tau) = e^{\pi i/3} \nu_{1/6,1/2} (0, 6 \tau)$

=>now i have a identity with theta series

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell me where you got this identity?

Comment: A complete proof is available [here](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/02/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-ramanujan-theory-5.html?m=0).

Comment: but that is to long
and i don't understand this